# How to underline a dynamic paragraph of text to the end of the line?

Tags: html, css, border, underline, text-decorations

I have a dynamic paragraph (the text will be changed ongoing) that I want to underline, however I want the underlines to span to the right edge of the container element rather than stopping at the end of the text. If you use text-decoration: underline it will just underline the text that exists on each line rather than the whole line

I can obviously manually split the lines up and then use a border bottom to span the whole width however the text is variable and can be changed so each line can't be manually specified. Is there a way to dynamically underline each line to the end without splitting them up?

Thanks everyone!

Dave

Comment: Can you change the text-align to justify? Not ideal, but it's the only non-script solution I can think of. That being said, not all browsers treat justify the same and it may not work in all.

Comment: is that even possible? you mean running the underline after the text towards "un-texted" area (to the right i suppose), am i right?

Comment: @Doozer Blake: I cannot use text-align justify as this screws up the design, the point is that it's left aligned text but the underline spans the whole width of the container.

Comment: @fskreuz Yes that is exactly what i mean! :)

Comment: @deshg: you could do a trick in css. create a background with "lines" that flush to the right just under the text. that is if the underline is of presentational use only

Comment: @deshg I understood the need, just wondered if justify could be used on that single element, not the entire design of your site. Everything else will likely be hacky, or possibly using some script to accomplish it

Comment: @fskreuz Surely this would require fixed heights between the lines on the background which wouldn't be suitable cross browser as they render text slightly differently (aside from what happens if users enlarge/reduce the text size)? Or am i missing your point? :) Cheers

Comment: @fskreuz posting answers as comments creates comment-box-chats.

Comment: @deshg yes, I think so. Note that enlarging text with zoom (`ctrl`+`+`) should enlarge images as well, including background images.

Comment: @ANeves: yeah, sorry about that. anyways, doing `CTRL`+`+` on older browsers (IE6 and i think IE7 for example) will only zoom text, thus break my suggestion. that's why i didn't post it as answer. :) but it will work on newer browsers with the full page zoom

Comment: @deshg: yeah, the images should be in sync with the text size or else, after the first few lines, it will "run-in" with the text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really - if you want to underline the text and not the paragraph.
Because either you target a block element - in which case you can only underline the bottom, or you target an inline element - in which case it will not stretch to the border.

You could justify the text, but it would still not underline the last line to the right edge of the text.

The only hack-around would be to use a fixed line height, and use a repeating background with an "underline-image" in such a way that the text would seem underlined.
I strongly advise against this, as it most likely works differently in different browsers.

Answer (score -1):

Try using `<u>`

```
<u><p>Some text</p></u>
```

Comment: -1: this would make absolutely no difference at all. Whichever rules you can target on the `ul`, you can also target on the `p`. So the `ul` without `li` is not only improper HTML, but also redundant.

Comment: It's proper in HTML5 where we can wrap block tags with non-block tags so you can also do `<a href="#"><li></li></a>` and so on. And also see that it's not `ul` tag but `u` tag.

Comment: D'OH! Misread as `ul`, sorry. It still doesn't work though, so I will maintain the -1: http://jsfiddle.net/ydcH7/ Also, you are not supposed to use `li` outside of `ul`/`ol`/`menu`: http://developers.whatwg.org/grouping-content.html#the-li-element

Comment: Yeah I know. But why are you still bothering with that `li`? After using `text-align: justify` works as you want.

Comment: @Hauleth I'm with ANeves, this has the same effect as specifying an underline property on the p, which just underlines the text (and doesn't span the whole way to the right). Plus the <u> tag is depreciated?

Comment: I was bothering with the `li` just for correctness' sake. Bit of an HTML-Nazi, maybe, but...

Comment: @ANeves Whoops, that's me not paying attention :)